# oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver not found by service bundle

Tags: apache-karaf

I'm using My batis under fuse and I have 4 bundles in my project

1. Model bundle which contains some beans
2. Dao bundle which connects to the DB by creating and using a SqlSessionTemplate bean
3. Service bundle which calls the Dao bundle
4. Web service bundle which calls the service bundle

I got a this error "org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver not found by service bundle"

and after importing oracle.jdbc package in the service bundle, the error dissapears

why does the service bundle load the Oracle driver? I think this is Dao bundle's responsibility.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?